# Magento 2 Commerce. Is there a cron that runs rabbitmq consumers?

Tags: magento2, rabbit-mq

- When cron runs I see a log that informs me that queue consumers failed to start.
- Is there a cron that runs rabbitmq consumers?

Answer (score 0):

There is a cron in module-message-queue that starts all consumers.

excerpt from /vendor/magento/module-message-queue/etc/crontab.xml

```
<group id="consumers">
    <job name="consumers_runner" instance="Magento\MessageQueue\Model\Cron\ConsumersRunner" method="run">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```